# evaluate complex square root

Tags: complex-numbers

$\sqrt{i^4}$
$=\sqrt{1}=1$ or
$=(\sqrt{i})^4$
$=(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+i\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})^4$
$=\exp(4\ln\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+i\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$
$=\exp(4i\frac{\pi}{4})=\exp(\pi)i=-1$
That is in case of the principle argument of the power function 
I think the second solution is the correct because i used the definition of the power function 
Does it correct or not ?

Comment: In short $-1$ is a square root of $i^4=1$. So what?

Comment: you agree the first result of the second ?

Comment: @HussienMohamed I agree with both, in the sense that both $1$ and $-1$ are fourth roots of $1$. In other words, $1^4=(-1)^4=1$. Is that what you want to know?

Comment: The fouth root of i is $i^(\frac{1}{4})$ but my qusetion is to evaluate the squre root if $i^4$

Answer (score 0):

The square rooth is not a well defined function in the complex numbers field.

$u=\sqrt{z}$ is a so called  multi-valued function with two different values that are the two complex numbers $u_1,u_2$ such that $u_1^2=u_2^2=z$.

In your case , since $i^4=1$ we have the two values $\sqrt{1}=\pm 1$.

If we use the symbol $\sqrt{\cdot}$ for the principal value of the complex square root, than, with the [usual definition of the principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_value#Square_root), we have, in this case:
$$
\sqrt{i^4}=\sqrt{e^{i2\pi}}=e^{i\pi}=-1
$$

Note that this is different from the definition of the square root in the filed of real numbers, were $y=\sqrt{x}$ is the the **positive** number $y$ such that $y^2=x$

Answer (score 0):

The convention is that when $0\leq x\in \Bbb R$  is that $0\leq \sqrt x\in \Bbb R.$ In particular $y=\sqrt x$ is an equation when $0\leq x\in \Bbb R.$ But $y=\sqrt x$ for non-real $x$ or for $0>x\in \Bbb R$  should not be taken literally as an equation. It only means that $x^2=y,$ and  there are $2$ possible values $x$ might be.

Failure to follow this will result in apparent paradoxes.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever we are talking about a one-to-many mapping, we need to specify what we mean when we perform operations on sets under such a mapping.

Because the mapping $$f : \mathbb C \to \mathbb C, \quad f(z) = z^2$$ satisfies $f(-z) = f(z)$ for all $z$, that is to say, every nonzero point in the image of $f$ has two distinct preimages in $\mathbb C$, the inverse mapping $$f^{-1} : \mathbb C \to \mathbb C, \quad f^{-1}(z) = z^{1/2}$$ is a **one-to-two** mapping:  each nonzero $z \in \mathbb C$ will admit two images under $f$, and because, unlike the reals, $\mathbb C$ is not a totally ordered field, it is not necessarily obvious which of these is the image that is "intended."

Thus, if wish to be general and think of complex-valued mappings as operations acting on subsets of $\mathbb C$, then it is natural to conclude that the mapping $$g : \mathbb C \to \mathbb C, \quad g(z) = (z^4)^{1/2}$$ would imply that $$g(i) = (i^4)^{1/2} = (1)^{1/2} = \{-1, 1\}.$$  This has nothing to do with $i$ or complex numbers *per se* but rather the fact that $1$ has **two** square roots, **even in the reals**.  Put simply, the meaning of $(1)^{1/2}$ is, "what is the set of all complex numbers such that their square equals $1$?"  And the answer to this is of course $\{-1, 1\}$.  Both are equally legitimate choices unless you impose some additional condition.

Comment: That is ok but the symbole 
$\sqrt{•}$ means the principle value of the square root , does it lead to the answer to be -1 only or 1?

Comment: @HussienMohamed Let me answer your question with another question:  what does the "principal" square root (note the correct spelling is principal, not "principle") mean for, say, $\sqrt{3-2i}$?  Can you say, then, that for a complex-valued mapping, that $\sqrt{i^4}$ should equal a single value?